# Convex and conical combination

Tags: plotting

The following code plots the conic combination of 3 vectors in R^3 but it is undesirable since I need to tweak the inequalities by hand:

```
v1 = {1, 0.2, 0.2}; v2 = {0.2, 2, 0.2}; v3 = {0.2, 0.2, 3};
a = Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ {v1, v2, v3}];
r = RegionPlot3D[
   Cross[v1, v3].{x, y, z} <= 0 && Cross[v1, v2].{x, y, z} >= 0 && 
    Cross[v2, v3].{x, y, z} >= 0, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic];
Show[r, a, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Is there any way to plot this more efficiently/neatly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a case for [`ConicHullRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConicHullRegion.html): it produces a clean image almost instantly:

```
v =  {{1, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.2, 2, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.2, 3}};

chr = ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}}, v]; 

Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ v,
  FaceForm @@ ({#, #}& @ {Opacity[.3], Red}), EdgeForm @ Blue, chr}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> Table[{0, 5}, 3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent that command does a neat and clean job. I am wondering how I can obtain the same smooth results by using ImplicitRegion and LinearSolve (see answer below). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
v1 = {1, 0.2, 0.2}; v2 = {0.2, 2, 0.2}; v3 = {0.2, 0.2, 3};
```

Define an [implicit region](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) that satisfies your constraints:

```
V = Transpose[{v1, v2, v3}];
R = ImplicitRegion[Thread[LinearSolve[V, {x, y, z}] >= 0], {x, y, z}]

(*    ImplicitRegion[
        1.03186 (1. x - 0.0939597 y - 0.0604027 z) >= 0 &&
        -0.0969529 (1. x - 5.28571 y + 0.285714 z) >= 0 &&
        -0.0623269 (1. x + 0.444444 y - 5.44444 z) >= 0,
        {x, y, z}]                                            *)

RegionPlot3D[R,
             PlotPoints -> 100,
             Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define a [parametric region](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html):

```
S = ParametricRegion[V . {a1, a2, a3},
      {{a1, 0, ∞}, {a2, 0, ∞}, {a3, 0, ∞}}]

(*    ParametricRegion[{{a1 + 0.2 a2 + 0.2 a3, 
                         0.2 a1 + 2 a2 + 0.2 a3,
                         0.2 a1 + 0.2 a2 + 3 a3}, 
                        a1 >= 0 && a2 >= 0 && a3 >= 0},
                       {a1, a2, a3}]
```

and plot it in the same way.

Comment: Very interesting. How can I remove the sawtooth effect? Looks awful even using >100 points which takes quite some time to render. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend using [@kglr's solution with `ConicHullRegion`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261649/26598). `ConicHullRegion` allows plotting with `Graphics3D`, which `ImplicitRegion` and `ParametricRegion` don't.

Answer (score 4):

If this is good enough, you could create the convex hull like:

```
v1 = {1, 0.2, 0.2}; v2 = {0.2, 2, 0.2}; v3 = {0.2, 0.2, 3};
Region[ConvexHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, v1, v2, v3}], Axes -> True, 
 Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

If you want to show more of the infinite region, you may include sums of the given vectors like:

```
Region[ConvexHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, v1, v2, v3, v1 + v2, v1 + v3, 
   v2 + v3, v1 + v2 + v3}], Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have Mathematica v11.0 and it seems the command "ConvexHullRegion" is not defined. In fact, I was interested in programming a command like that one by using standard vector operations, which is done in the next answer.

Answer (score 3):

RegionPlot3D can be slow, I think because each mesh point gets checked against the constraints.
Setting terms for the cross products so that they only get calculated once speeds up the plotting by a factor of 15 on my system.

```
v1 = {1, 0.2, 0.2}; v2 = {0.2, 2, 0.2}; v3 = {0.2, 0.2, 3};
a = Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ {v1, v2, v3}];
v1xv3 = Cross[v1, v3];
v1xv2 = Cross[v1, v2];
v2xv3 = Cross[v2, v3];
r = RegionPlot3D[
  v1xv3 . {x, y, z} <= 0 && v1xv2 . {x, y, z} >= 0 && 
   v2xv3 . {x, y, z} >= 0, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, AxesLabel -> Automatic];
Show[r, a, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```